# How to turn off Application insights javascript in embedded cshtml views

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I have a view Email1.cshtml (Build Action=Embedded Resource):

```
@model Email1Model;

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, @Model.Name</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I render the cshtml view to string using [ViewRenderService](https://gist.github.com/ieski/f868df128a58b69f95ab78d60c1bc0a4). The only difference is that I use `IRazorViewEngine.GetView()` instead of FindView();

However, in the output I some application insights stuff:

```
<html> <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){....);

        window.appInsights=appInsights;
        appInsights.trackPageView();

    </script> </head> <body>
    <h1>Hello, Liero</h1> </body> </html>
```

In the startup.cs:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(opt => opt.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
```

### Question:

How do I turn off the javascript in specific views that I render using ViewRenderService?

Answer (score -1):

If you _layout.cshtml has @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript) that will inject application insights javascript into each page, you could try adding a conditional in _layout.cshtml using:

```
@if (condition true for instrumenting)
{
    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  The issue is conditionally doing the within the _viewimports.cshtml
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet